# Strategy to consolidate Java webapp configuration files for multiple deployments

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, configuration

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find anything describing exactly what I wanted.  I'm building a webapp that has a number of different properties that need to change depending on the environment in addition to a number of `.properties` configuration files that need to change as well.  Right now I have a global enum (`DEVELOPMENT`, `STAGING`, and `PRODUCTION`) that is used to determine which string constants are used in the application and then I utilize a bunch of comments in the configuration files to switch between database servers, etc.  There has got to be a better way to do this...I'd ideally like to be able to make one change in one file (A large block comment would be fine...) to adjust these configurations.  I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3463247/150771) where the answer is to utilize JNDI which I really like, but it would seem as though I would need to call that from a servlet that starts up or a bean that gets initialized on start in order to use it for my log4j or JDBC configuration files.

Does anybody have any strategies for dealing with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this strategy will apply to your situation, but in the past I've successfully used our build tool (ant in that case) to build different war files depending on the profile. So you would have multiple log4j configuration files in your source tree, and then delete the ones you don't want from the final build depending on the profile that was used to build it.

Traceability becomes slightly hard (i.e. difficult sometimes to figure out which one was used to build it), but it's a very clean solution, from your code perspective, since it's all done in your build script.

Comment: I'd definitely thought about this and I think it's a nice solution.  My only problem is that right now I'm not using a build tool, just Eclipse (bad, I know).

Answer (score 0):

We store all our default configuration values in a single XML file. During deployment we apply an XML patch (RFC-5261) with values specific to the environment.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5261
http://xmlpatch.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your properties files are made up of 95% *name=value* pairs that are identical across all your deployment environments and 5% of *name=value* pairs that change from one deployment environment to another.

If this assumption is correct, then you could try something like the following pseudocode.

```
void generateRuntimeConfigFiles(int deploymentMode)
{
    String[] searchAndReplacePairs;

    if (deploymentMode == Constants.PRODUCTION) {
        searchAndReplacePairs = ...
    } else if (deploymentMode == Constants.STAGING) {
        searchAndReplacePairs = ...
    } else { // Constants.DEVELOPMENT
        searchAndReplacePairs = ...
    }
    String[] filePairs = new String[] {
        "log4j-template.properties", "log4j.properties",
        "jdbc-template.properties",  "jdbc.properties",
        "foo-template.xml",          "foo.xml",
        ...
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < filePairs.length; i += 2) {
        String inFile = filePairs[i + 0];
        String ouFile = filePairs[i + 1];
        searchAndReplaceInFile(inFile, outFile,
                               searchAndReplacePairs);
    }
}
```

Your application calls `generateRuntimeConfigFiles()` *before* initialising anything else that might rely on properties/XML files.

Now the only problem you have to deal with is how to store and retrieve different settings for `searchAndReplacePairs`. Perhaps you could obtain them from files with names such as `production.properties`, `staging.properties` and `development.properties`.

If the above approach is appealing to you, then email me for the source code of `searchAndReplaceInFile()` to save you having to re-invent the wheel. You can find my email address from the "info" box in my Stackoverflow profile.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Apache Commons Configuration. It provides all the plumbing for dealing with different configurations depending on your environment.

http://commons.apache.org/configuration